# Redis serializer properties in SCDF

Tags: redis, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm using a splitter and an aggregator in `SCDF 2.10.3` and I want to cache messages in `Redis`.

Here is a simple example stream : `http | splitter | aggregator | log`

This stream works fine without Redis. But when I added Redis configuration to the aggregator, I get an serialization exception because the object does not implement Serializable. This is an known problem with Redis default serializer but I can't find a way to set `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` class as Redis serializer through the properties I pass to the stream and I prefer not to fork the aggregator app !

Is there a way to change the Redis serializer with a property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that via properties. Feel free to raise a GH issue and we will think what and how can be done from the project perspective.

Only solution I see at the moment is to have your own `RedisMessageStore` bean with respective `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` injected. Keep in mind that this one has to be supplied with a `JacksonJsonUtils.messagingAwareMapper()` for a proper `Message` abstraction (de)serialization.

See more info in Spring Cloud DataFlow how to enhance a classpath for steam applications: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#extend-classpath

Comment: Also: would you mind explaining how you get an Object instead of a `byte[]` in that aggregator?

Comment: The GH issue is here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/issues/500. But I still would like to understand how you end up with a POJO, not `byte[]` as an input for the aggregator processor?